# Openmeeting load balancing http

Tags: http, load-balancing, red5, openmeetings

Anyone have try to load balancing openmeeting with http ?
i have installed on my server, but how i can load balancing it with http ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

load balancing via HTTP is not really that interesting, as OpenMeetings main protocol is RTMP and RTMPT.

You might review the clustering docs:
http://openmeetings.apache.org/Clustering.html

However those docs refer to Openmeetings 2.1 which is not yet released.
Maxim committed those changes 1-2 weeks ago.
You might connect to the mailing list at:
http://incubator.apache.org/openmeetings/mail-lists.html
To get further information.

Sebastian